# What is the content of an m-parallelotope in n dimensions?

Tags: linear-algebra, volume

How do I calculate the m-dimensional content of a parallelotope given by m vectors which are all n-dimensional (m<n)? For example 3 vectors spanning a parallelepiped in high dimensional space.

I found how to use the determinant for n=m, but what about m<n? Is there a quick way with QR decomposition somehow?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'content'. Certainly the volume is $0$ if $m < n$. Just consider the case $n = 3$ to see that: the volume of a square is $0$ because it is flat.

Comment: The $m$-dimensional content is not $n$-dimensional content (volume). Look at the Gram determinant. Geometrically, complete your parallelepiped to an $n$-dimensional parallelepiped by appending an orthonormal basis for the $(n-m)$-dimensional space orthogonal to your given parallelepiped.

Comment: A square in 3D has still some area. That's why I mean m-dimensional volume of a parallelotope spanned by m vectors, but in n dimensions (n>m).

Comment: Did you understand my comment, @Gerenuk?

Comment: To see how to do this for 2-dimensional area in 3-dimensional space (for example), you might find my video helpful: https://youtu.be/9IswLDsEWFk

Comment: @TedShifrin Maybe I understood. But deriving a basis which is perpendicular to all my previous vectors does not seem much simpler than the initial question. It seems I can simply use Gram-Schmidt on my vectors and multiply their lengths. But a full equation would be nice.

Comment: As I said, look up the Gram determinant.